# Calendar notification on macOS not going away

Tags: macos, notifications, calendar, big-sur

The calendar app on macOS Big Sur keeps showing me a red (1) notification icon that is not going away:

[image]

I don't know what entry is causing the notification. The invitation list is empty. I tried resetting the Exchange account but the badge came back up. I tried resetting the dock as well to no avail.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: as it turns out, the notification disappeared as magically as it turned up. I'll leave open this thread anyway in case anyone finds any non-magical solutions that (s)he wishes to share here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which type of calendar is causing the notification (iCloud, Exchange, or a calendar subscription from a URL)? Is the calendar entry that is causing the notification an invitation or have you created it? Could you add a screenshot of the notification (make sure to redact any sensitive information)?

Comment: @jaume, thank you! It is an Exchange account. I don't know what entry is causing the notification. The invitation list is empty. There is only the red badge at the app icon showing a (1).

Comment: If you have access to Microsoft Outlook, do you see a pending invitation as explained here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/pending-invitations-in-outlook/5a5c31a0-e50d-452f-add9-2b37a9e6e33b? If you have access to your Exchange account through the web (aka Outlook Web App), do you see notifications as explained here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getting-started-in-outlook-web-app-0062c7be-f8e3-486e-8b14-5c1f793ceefd? If you don't, you may need to delete and recreate the account in System Preferences > Internet Accounts.

Comment: @jaume, there are no notifications in the outlook web app. And recreating the account didn't solve it either unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a Siri suggestion, that wasn't showing in my calendar because I don't have the "Siri suggestions" calendar visible. Finding the event Siri was suggesting and ignoring it, made the notification go away.